# Check whether a string contains a specified pattern?

Tags: java, regex

I've been asked this question in a java dev interview.

Given a string entirely made of square brackets `[` and `]`, find if it has the pattern `[*][*][*]` inside. (the `*` here represents a 0 or more balanced bracket strings). meaning, check if it has 3 or more of`[]` inside at-least any one of`[]`.

Examples:

for `[[][[][][]]]`  expected answer is true as it has `[][][]` inside it.

for `[[]][[][]]` expected answer is false as it has less than 3 consecutive `[]` inside any one of `[]`

for `[[[]][][[]]]` expected answer is true as it has `[..][][..]` inside it. It doesn't matter if there are 0 or more `[]` inside a `[]` .

**IMPORTANT**: The input string is already balanced. It doesn't need to checked for balance.

The question is to find a specific nested pattern inside an already balanced string. The input to this problem is a "**balanced**" expression. The output is a boolean answer specifying whether it contains the specified pattern of brackets **yes** or **no**.

Comment: @Pshemo the open and closing brackets may be nested , so simple contains won't work. See example 3 for clarification

Comment: In that case you probably need to explain it farther in problem description. Also `[*][*][*]` isn't clear since `*` has very specific meaning in regex which you probably didn't meant in that example.

Comment: Your first example is not balanced. Should it still return true?

Comment: @NomadMaker i screwed up, it is balanced, i'll edit the question. The input is always balanced.

Comment: Shouldn't second case match `[*][*][*]`? Notice that `[[]][[][]]` can be split into `[[]]` `[[]` `[]]` (each of those parts can match `[*]` - assuming that `*` represents *any string*).

Comment: @Pshemo the * represents a balanced bracket expression. I'll edit the question to make it clear

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are not the way to go for this kind of problem. They don't work particularly well with nested structures because of recursion.

This is a prefect problem for using stacks (FILO) for example. I'd recommend you take a look at those.

```
class Node
{
    private final Node parent;
    private final List<Node> subNodes = new LinkedList<>();

    Node(Node parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    static Node buildFrom(String str)
    {
        Node start = new Node(null);
        Node current = start;

        for (char ch : str.toCharArray())
        {
            if (ch == '[') //Create new subnode
            {
                Node newNode = new Node(current);
                current.subNodes.add(newNode);
                current = newNode;
            }
            else //Step back
            {
                current = current.parent;
            }
        }
        return start;
    }

    boolean hasTripleNodes()
    {
        if (this.subNodes.size() >= 3) //Found triple+ nodes
        {
            return true;
        }
        else //Continue recursion
        {
            for (Node subNode: this.subNodes)
            {
                if (subNode.hasTripleNodes())
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    //DEMO
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Node nodes = Node.buildFrom("[[][[][][]]]");
        System.out.println(nodes.hasTripleNodes()); //writes true

        nodes = Node.buildFrom("[[]][[][]]");
        System.out.println(nodes.hasTripleNodes()); //writes false

        nodes = Node.buildFrom("[[[]][][[]]]");
        System.out.println(nodes.hasTripleNodes()); //writes true
    }
}
```

Comment: I know how to use stacks to check if it is balanced, but i can't figure out how to use that in this particular case. Can u guide me to a similar problem or any suggestion on how to get started

Comment: On further reading of the question I think you'd be better off using some kind of tree structure. Represent each bracket (pair) as a node and create sub-nodes for each bracket (pair) you find in it. If in the final tree there is any single node with 3 or more subnodes, then it fits your criteria.

Comment: Can u give me idea on how to construct this tree.I can't comprehend how to have  root node of the tree that is concatenated first and last character of a given string.

Comment: @NoobScript: When I am checking my code for balanced parentheses, I generally read my code left to right, count up by one  for each left parenthesis, and count down for each right parenthesis.  If I reach zero by the time I get to the end of my line of code, the parentheses are balanced.  Maybe you could do something similar in your code?

Comment: I added my code. Basically all you do is create a new subnode and step into it on an opening bracket, or step out on a closing bracket

Comment: @RobertHarvey the input is already balanced. The problem is to find if a node has more than 2 children if the input is represented as a tree

Comment: @DavidBose thanks, this looks like it could work.

Comment: Cheers! Have fun with it

Comment: whoever marked this question as a duplicate of balanced expression check, please explain why you though it is. The question makes it very clear that it has nothing to with balancing.